# How do I test angular2 services that use moment?

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am trying to test an Angular (angular2) service I wrote that uses momentJS, but since moment lives in the browser I keep getting reference errors. Is there anyway to tell karma/jasmine how to use moment in a unit test? Here is the error I get:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: moment in karma-test-shim.js (line 33814)
```

Here are my tests:

```
describe('isDateBeforeToday', () => {
        it('should return true if date is before today', () => {
            let past = new Date(2016, 1, 1);
            expect(UnitService.isDateBeforeToday(past)).toEqual(true);

            past = new Date();
            past.setDate(past.getDate() - 1);
            past.setHours(23);
            expect(UnitService.isDateBeforeToday(past)).toEqual(true);
        });

        it('should return false if date is today', () => {
            let today = new Date();
            expect(UnitService.isDateBeforeToday(today)).toEqual(false);
        });

        it('should return false if date is in future', () => {
            let future = new Date();
            future.setDate(future.getDate() + 1);
            expect(UnitService.isDateBeforeToday(future)).toEqual(false);
        });
    });
```

Here is the function I'm trying to test:

```
static isDateBeforeToday(date: Date) {
        let momentDate = moment(date);
        let now = moment();
        return (momentDate.diff(now, 'days') < 0);
    }
```

karma-test-shim.js (based on angular examples):

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

require('moment');

var appContext = require.context('../__tests__', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

karma.conf.js:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.test');

module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {
    basePath: '',
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 20000, // had to increase this for component unit tests to work

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      {pattern: './karma-test-shim.js', watched: false}
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      './karma-test-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress','kjhtml'], //leave coverage reporter in for now, even though coverage not working

    coverageReporter: {
        type: 'html',
        dir: '../coverage/'
    },

    browsers: ['phantomJS_without_security'],
    customLaunchers: {
        chrome_without_security: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--disable-web-security']
        },
        phantomJS_without_security: {
            base:'PhantomJS',
            options: {
                windowName: 'Portal-tests',
                settings: {
                    webSecurityEnabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },

    phantomjsLauncher: {
        // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
        exitOnResourceError: true
    },

    client: {
        captureConsole: true
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true
  };

  config.set(_config);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing something pretty hacky. I used require to import the moment library from my node_modules and attached it to the window object in the beforeEach of every test class that used moment. If anyone has a nicer, less hacky, answer please post.

```
import { UnitService } from '../../src/app/services/unit.service';
let moment = require('moment');

describe('UnitService', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        (<any>window).moment = moment;
    });

// Tests that use a function that uses moment go here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently and solved by including moment in testing framework. In our case, moment is attached to the window, so ended up doing that in our test config like:

```
window.moment = require('moment-recur');
```

You might have to do something similar to suit your case.

Answer (score 0):

For me the resolution was to import MomentModule in my TestBed

```
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
    ...
    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    imports: [MomentModule],
    ...
```

taken from https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/issues/165